# Are the shrine names supposed to mean something?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

While watching a speedrun, I've come across something weird between versions of Breath of the Wild. Between languages, it seems the shrine names change. Not completely, but to me it is a weird change.

[image]

On the left is the GameGrumps playthrough, in English. The first shrine in the game is named 'Oman Au'.

On the right, is a speedrun, using the French version. The first shrine in the game is named 'Ma'Ohno'.

It would be a weird thing to change in localisation, letting me think that Shrine names might mean more than just names.

So is it just a localisation thing, or is there more meaning to the shrine names I'm not seeing?

Comment: Is your claim that "Names never change during Localization?" because all of the 700+ pokémon beg to differ...

Comment: I would assume it's localized translations from Hylian.  Since Shrine and Sanctuary are the English/French portion of the name.  'Oman Au' isn't English, uses English Characters, puts its likely a Hylian name translated to English since the English to French translation doesn't come out to Ma'Ohno

Comment: @RavenDreamer This assumtion is false. I realized this summer after opening Pokemon Go in french that most pokemon are a combination of a few words, and those words are translated to give the name in French. Ex: Blastoise -> Blast + Tortoise in french is Tortank -> Tortue (Tortoise) + Tank (Tank). I don't see such a comparison that can be done with the shrine names.

Comment: When translating names from a non-roman alphabet to a roman alphabet the localization team often change the name a bit to match the original sound it has while also making it a little more "usual" to the language. Take, for instance, the name Link. Originally (in japanese) it literally translates to Rinku (http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Link). By pronouncing it in japanese (Rinku), the sound is very close to it's name adapted in english (Link).

Comment: @Ramhound Breath of the Wild uses 6th Hylian IIRC, which translates to English. And so does Ancient Shiekah; the letters map to Latin and give English words when translated (e.g. the platform in front of the monk has "GOAL" written on it).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Shrines (and their corresponding monks) can be linked to Zelda staff members.**

According to [this wiki page](http://zelda.gamepedia.com/Oman_Au_Shrine) on gamepedia:

**Oman Au is an anagram of Aonuma.**
Eiji Aonuma is the lead producer for The Legend of Zelda series.

The *Japanese* name of the shrine is    *マ・オーヌの祠 (Ma Ōnu no Hokora)*,   meaning **Ma Ōnu Shrine**
The *Italian* name of the shrine is     *Sacrario di Mau Ona*,              meaning **Mau Ona Shrine**.
The *French* name of the shrine is  *Sactuaire de Ma'Ohnu*,             meaning **Ma Ohnu Shrine**.

These are all anagrams of different translations / romanizations of the name Aonuma.

Quoting from this video of [DidYouKnowGaming](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FLuGFR3gZwI&t=11m5s):

> **Aonuma is not the only developer that was referenced in this way**:
>   Other monks and shrines are also named after zelda staff:
>
> Zalta Wa Shrine   -> Satoru Takizawa ( Art Director )
>   Sasa Kai Shrine
>   -> Hiroshi Sakasai ( Designer )
>   Katosa Aug Shrine -> Katsuhisa Sato ( Physics Programmer )
>
> Naming each shrine and monk after a member of the staff was actually
>   suggested by Satoru Takizawa himself.

Based on these examples, not all shrine names are direct anagrams of staff member names, which might make correlating more names to staff members a bit more difficult.

It is still unclear to me whether such a link does indeed exist for every shrine/monk, or that this was only suggested but never fully realized.

Following the sources in the description of the DidYouKnowGaming video, 
I came back to gamepedia, which has [a page with namesakes for many more monks](https://zelda.gamepedia.com/index.php?title=Monk).

Interesting to note is that on the same day I originally posted this answer, a user named TriforceTony added a lot more names to this list!

Comment: They probably are, or partners and/or children.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I seem to recall someone, when mentioning the Aonuma anagram on Reddit, also saying that at least one other shrine is a developer anagram as well.